# explain this javascript construct please

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am not too familiar with javascript. Can someone please explain this construct to me?

```
[{a:"asdfas"},{a:"ghdfh",i:54},{i:76,j:578}]
```

What does this construct declare? I can see that this is an array that consists of 3 elements, right? And every element in this array is a class, which is declared in JSON format, isn't it? And I do not need to use any scripts to use JSON, do I?

Comment: What is the question? Yes its a array of 3 elements, each a object. JSON format specifies the keys to be enclosed in quotes aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply an array composed of 3 elements. Each element is an object. The first one has the `a` key with associated 'asdfas' value. The second one i key with 54 value etc etc

it could be built in this way :

```
var arr = []; //[] <= array

var first = {}; // {} <= object
first.a = "asdfas"; // object.key = value, same by doing var first = {a:"asdfas"}
arr.push(first); //pushing an object inside the array

//arr status: [{a:"asdfas"}]

var second = {};
second.a = "ghdfh";
second.i = 54;
arr.push(second);

//arr status: [{a:"asdfas"},{a:"ghdfh",i:54}]

var third = {};
third.i = 76;
third.j = 578;
arr.push(third);

//arr status: [{a:"asdfas"},{a:"ghdfh",i:54},{i:76,j:578}]

alert(arr[2].j) //third element of the array => object => key j => alerts j value 578
```

Comment: var first = {}; - is that a creation of an empty object which you extend with a property later?

Comment: Exactly, you could also create an object directly inside an array, but it's just to explain how it works :) .. I've just added some comments ;)

Answer (score 4):

This declares an array of 3 objects. The first object of this array contains one string property `a = "asdfas"`. The second object in the array contains two properties `a = "ghdfh"` and `i = 54`. And the last object contains two numeric properties `a = 76` and `j = 578`. So this represents a javascript object and you don't need to declare any scripts to use it:

```
var array = [ { a: "asdfas" }, 
              { a: "ghdfh", i: 54 }, 
              { i: 76, j: 578 }
            ];
alert(array[1].i); // prints the i property of the second item in the array: 54
```

Comment: *"So this represents a JSON notation for declaring objects..."* This just adds to the confusion people have between JSON data and javascript objects. They're just an Array and object literals. Sure they could be stringified into JSON data, but until then, they have nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @patrick dw, very good point. I've updated my answer to take it into account. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

That is an array of object literals.  You do not need any scripts or special libraries to use JSON objects within a script, but depending on your implementation, you may need to use a script to use JSON within AJAX requests.  For more info, see: http://www.json.org/

EDIT: corrected per discussion in comments.

Comment: No, that is not JSON. Those are javascript object literals.

Comment: I was going to come back with a "JSON is a subset of object literals, you're nitpicking!".  But then I noticed that there are missing quotes around the property names, and other syntactical problems that make the string he posted not valid JSON.  I stand corrected, sir. +1

Comment: Yeah, I hate to nitpick, but it is such a common (and understandable) mistake. Ultimately, if the data isn't a text string, it isn't JSON. Thanks for bearing with me. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of 3 objects.

The brackets `[]` indicate an array.

Each item within the array is an object, as indicated by the curly braces `{}`. You can think of each of these like a hash table, where `a : "asdfas"` means that you can reference `a` to look up the string value. For example:

```
var data = {a:"asdfas"};
alert( data.a ); // Echos "asdfas"
```

Regarding your question:

> And I do not need to use any scripts to use JSON, do I?

No, JSON is just JavaScript Object Notation, so it is just JavaScript code. However, you will need/want to use a 3rd party library (such as json2.js) if you need to encode a JavaScript data structure as JSON or if you need to decode JSON from a string.